# How to determine a point is inside 2d mesh or not (CGAL)?

Tags: graphics, geometry, cgal

I'm using CGAL for geometry processing. After doing delaunay triangulation, I need to check whether a point inside or outside of 2D mesh:

[image]

Comment: If an answer replies to your question, you should "accept" it, to mark the question as "answered" (and give reputation points to the poster).

Answer (score 5):

If you have used the 2D mesh generator of CGAL, you can:

- first, localize your point `p` in the triangulation:
  `Tr::Face_handle fh = tr.locate(p);`
- then, check if the corresponding face `fh` is in the domain or not:
  `bool is_inside = fh->is_in_domain();`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about efficiency, just test your point against all triangles (the point must be on the inner side of the three triangle edges). This takes O(n).

If you do care, use the techniques of efficient point location in a planar subdivision. Preferably the trapezoidal decomposition. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_location#Trapezoidal_decomposition. You will achieve O(Log(n)) query time, after O(n.Log(n)) preprocessing and O(n) storage (randomized).

You can also consider the jump-and-walk approach that can result in O(Sqrt(n)) queries with no preprocessing. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jump-and-Walk_algorithm.  check http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/techreports/UCAM-CL-TR-728.pdf.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I found out CGAL has an implementation of trapezoidal decomposition, I'll try to find out about it :)

Comment: Uhm, I'm still working about this problem with CGAL, it seems both trapezoidal decompostion and jump and walk aren't quite straightforward. Moreover I'm also trying whether AABB tree is also work or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [arrangements](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/3.3/doc_html/cgal_manual/Arrangement_2/Chapter_main.html). The arrangement pre-processes any 2d planar subdivision (including a tri-mesh with holes) and can answer point location queries. So you'll be able to ask it which tri-facet contains the point in question. If it shows up empty, you know your point is outside.

Googling gave a few links about the literature on this subject. [Here](http://www.cs.uu.nl/docs/vakken/ga/slides6.pdf)'s one I found.